# Swift: Make sure no two arrays are the same

Tags: arrays, swift, random, arc4random

I'm randomly creating for different arrays with 4 random numbers (1-4) randomly. But how do I make sure that no two arrays are the same?

For example: [1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1], [1,2,2,1], [1,2,3,4] <- first and last were generated the same randomly, how can i check to see if it's random and if it is generate it again, and if it's not, continue?

This is my code but i don't think it's working because a couple of times i'll see two of the same arrays...

```
func randomNumbersArray(i: UInt32) -> [Int] {
    let r = [Int(arc4random_uniform(i) + 1),
             Int(arc4random_uniform(i) + 1),
             Int(arc4random_uniform(i) + 1),
             Int(arc4random_uniform(i) + 1)]
    return r
}

func arrays() {
    let main = randomNumbersArray(4)
    qArray = main
    aArray = main
    bArray = randomNumbersArray(4)
    cArray = randomNumbersArray(4)
    dArray = randomNumbersArray(4)

    if aArray == bArray || aArray == cArray || aArray == dArray ||
        bArray == cArray || bArray == dArray || cArray == dArray {
        bArray = randomNumbersArray(4)
        cArray = randomNumbersArray(4)
        dArray = randomNumbersArray(4)
    }
    print(aArray)
    print(bArray)
    print(cArray)
    print(dArray)
}
```

Comment: If things are random, they could repeat -- that's normal, random behavior. Also, there are not a large number of unique arrays with 1-4 in them.  What happens when you run out?

Comment: @LouFranco Well, there is 256 of them, that's not so bad if you need only 4. Technically, you could just generate 4 numbers in 0..255 range and generate the arrays from those numbers (every two bits represent a digit). It would be also completely possible to pregenerate all the arrays and then pick from them randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
func randomNumbersArray(i: UInt32) -> [Int] {
    let r = [Int(arc4random_uniform(i) + 1),
             Int(arc4random_uniform(i) + 1),
             Int(arc4random_uniform(i) + 1),
             Int(arc4random_uniform(i) + 1)]
    return r
}

func arrays() {
    var randArrays = [[Int]]()

    repeat {
        let newArray = randomNumbersArray(4)

        if !randArrays.contains{ $0 == newArray } {
            randArrays.append(newArray)
        }
    } while randArrays.count < 4

    //...
}
```

Comment: To be clear: this will have increasingly worse performance as the values of `i` decrease, and will even infinitely loop if you try to make more unique arrays than possible for the given value of `i`.

Comment: With a little adjustment, this worked perfectly. Thank you !

Comment: Also, when you know the size of `Array` ahead of time, it's best to use the [`
init(count:repeatedValue:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/Array/s:FSacFT5countSi13repeatedValuex_GSax_) initializer to preallocate the size. It's not so important here (with a size of just 4), but it's good practice for larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Make an Array to store your Arrays. Whenever you generate a new array, check `.contains(_:)`, and keep generating new arrays until it's `false`.